# How to format invitations so they work well in Outlook and IBM Notes

Tags: email, outlook, lotus-notes, icalendar

Our C# application sends e-mail invitations using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`. We used to format them with HTML in a way that looked proper in Microsoft Outlook. Now they must work out in IBM Notes, too.

However Notes seems to refuse any attempt to style anything in an invitation. It extracts the text parts from the HTML and puts them as unformatted text into its description field.

Our implementation uses `text/calendar` with a `ALT-REP` reference and two alternative views:

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(descriptionContent, contentType);
message.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);

contentType = new ContentType("text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8");
contentType.Parameters.Add("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(invitationContent, contentType);
message.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);
```

Where as `descriptionContent` is HTML-formatted content.

The `invitationContent`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n");
builder.Append("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n");
builder.Append("VERSION:2.0\r\n");
builder.Append("METHOD:REQUEST\r\n");
builder.Append("BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n");
builder.Append("ORGANIZER;CN=\"The Full Name\":MAILTO:the-to-address@example.org\r\n");
builder.Append("SUMMARY;CHARSET=iso-8859-1;LANGUAGE=de-ch:Some Title\r\n");
builder.Append("DTSTART:" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'}", invitationStart) + "\r\n");
builder.Append("DTEND:" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'}", invitationEnd) + "\r\n");
builder.Append("LOCATION;CHARSET=iso-8859-1:Some address\r\n");
builder.Append("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "\r\n");
builder.Append("DTSTAMP:" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'}", DateUtil.GetToday()) + "\r\n");
builder.Append("DESCRIPTION;ALTREP=\"CID:<eventDescriptionHTML>\"\r\n");
builder.Append("BEGIN:VALARM\r\n");
builder.Append("TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n");
builder.Append("ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n");
builder.Append("DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n");
builder.Append("END:VALARM\r\n");
builder.Append("END:VEVENT\r\n");
builder.Append("END:VCALENDAR");
```

As an example, with the `descriptionContent` of

```
...
<h1>A title</h1>
<h2>A subtitle</h2>
<p>A paragraph</p>
...
```

This would display right in MS Outlook but in Notes, the invitation description contains a plain "A title A subtitle A paragraph" text.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev - I understand why you removed the outlook tag. However I added it consciously. The question reads ..."in Outlook *and* Lotus Notes". It will not help if I change the format of the e-mail such that it works fine in Lotus Notes but is messed up in Outlook in turn.

Answer (score -1):

You can export Notes calendar entries as ICS format from the Notes calendar in the Notes client.

Create an invitation using the description you want, export it and check the .ics to see what you need to add to your code

Comment: Thank you, just gave it a try. Unfortunately while exporting the ICS file, Lotus Notes removed the formatting. When I re-imported the ICS file, the formatting was lost.